# Alternate client for Cisco Unified Personal Communicator protocol

Tags: chat

At work we have an in-house chat system using CUPC. Does anyone else out there use this?
There are a few things I do not like about this client:

- Where's the chat log? If I close the window, I have no way of getting my conversation back.
- Tabbed interface? That would be nice. I hate having multiple chat windows up, having to arrange them around my desktop as more people start talking to me.
- I don't like that I have to use this one-off application for particular *this* protocol when other chat clients will handle 99% of the other protocols I use.

Tell me: Is the protocol an open standard for which other applications have support? (pidgin, adium, digsby, etc.) If not, can I overcome these issues from within CUPC? Perhaps there are newer versions of the client that overcome these issues.

Comment: which OS and client version would this be?

Comment: Windows XP 7.0 (1.13056)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMPP is only in CUPS/CUPC version 8.  However, in response to your original questions, there is a way to save IM transcripts, go to your CUPC preferences and under IM select the checkbox for "Automatically log chat transcripts to folder location" and select the location you want them saved.  Also, as far as tabbed IM windows, we use CUPS 7 with CUPC 7 clients here and there is tabbed messaging.  Any other questions feel free to email me at rmcgurn@rcserveny.com.

CUPC is a client for the Unified Presence Server, which does MUCH more than merely provide an in-house instant messaging system.

Answer (score 2):

CUPC uses Jabber / XMPP - We use Pidgin on Windows for CUPC just fine.